# How influential was Lorenz' work?

Tags: math-history, chaos-theory

I've recently read [an article](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/magazine/physicstoday/article/66/5/10.1063/PT.3.1977) in *Pour la Science* (a French equivalent of the *Scientific American*, with an overall very good quality) on the history of Chaos theory. Essentially, the article goes straight from Poincaré's work on celestial mechanics to the discovery Lorenz' equations, jumping over sixty or seventy years as if nothing had happened:

> Poincaré’s results, independent findings by Jacques Hadamard, and experimental hints of chaos seen by their contemporaries were dismissed by many as pathologies or artifacts of noise or methodological shortcomings and were referred to as a “gallery of monsters.”4 It would take nearly another century for chaos theory to gain a lasting foothold.

This view is not isolated. For instance, on the page for Edward Lorenz' [Kyoto prize](http://www.inamori-f.or.jp/laureates/k07_b_edward/prf_e.html):

> He made his boldest scientific achievement in discovering "deterministic chaos," a principle which has profoundly influenced a wide range of basic sciences and brought about one of the most dramatic changes in mankind's view of nature since Sir Isaac Newton.

Sure, these things are meant to be hyperbolic. However, he is not credited with "oustanding achievements in chaos theory", but with single-handedly creating the field.

On the over hand, while Lorenz' equations are interesting and exhibit a variety of interesting phenomenons (not the least being Lorenz' attractor), from a mathematical point of view, I don't really see it as the beginning of a field. Ergodic theory has been around since thirty to forty years, so the idea of "deterministic chaos" has been there for quite some time. The years around Lorenz' work also saw the studies of Anosov (Anosov diffeomorphisms), Ruelle (statistical mechanics), Smale (horseshoe map)... While I can somewhat grasp the importance of the results of the later authors, I don't really see how Lorenz' work is in any way central.

So, in short, I don't see why Lorenz has been given such a central place in the narratives around chaos theory. What am I missing?

Comment: I read a similar account in the book by Strogatz, "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos."  It seems like when he discovered his strange attractor, he also realized what was going on at quite a deep level.  His first paper on the subject apparently contained a lot of insight.

Comment: Ergodic theory is not the same as deterministic chaos.

Comment: @nonlinearism: There is a good overlap between the two fields, which includes the study of Lorenz' system (at least with the "strange attractor"). Anyway, if you can explain how Lorenz' work was really different from previous work in ergodic theory, that would be a fitting answer.

Comment: I have severe reservations about your claimed overlap. Ergodic theory refers to study of systems with a invariant measure, and was usually studied in relation with statistical mechanics etc. Ergodic hypothesis was central to the theory of the time. Lorenz' work on the other hand was about system with no invariant measure, where things like Ergodic hypothesis don't even make any sense.

Comment: @nonlinearism: That depends on what you are talking about. If it's the original hydrodynamics motivation, I agree. However, most of the citations (e.g. the article I quoted) are about Lorenz' system of differential equations. And the cases usually shown as "deterministic chaos" for Lorenz' system are the one with a strange attractor, that is, a compact invariant set. So of course there are invariant measures; what is less trivial (but true) is that they also show the complexity of the dynamics.