# Why was the Butterfly Effect so surprising?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, dynamical-systems, math-history

I was reading a popular science book about the history of  Chaos theory and was curious about the part when Edward Lorenz discovered the so-called *butterfly effect*.

Long story short, he omitted to key in an extra decimal place into his computer simulation of weather, thinking that it wouldn't make much a difference, but instead got a completely different result in a relatively short period of time. This led him to his theory about chaotic system.

Sure, it might be counter-intuitive to think that a small error can magnify that fast, but even with hindsight this shouldn't be THAT surprising at all. I mean, for example, Hadamard had coined the term well-posedness and sensitivity to initial condition decades before that. Edward Lorenz, being a fine mathematician as he was, should be familiar with these things shouldn't he?

I'm not an expert in this so there could be many points that I overlooked. I hope that the question is not too broad.

Comment: Before Lorenz, I think people assumed that such ill-posed problems were very rare -- pathological examples, if you like. Lorenz showed that they were very common.

Comment: In the future, consider asking questions like these at [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: An older question with the same intent, some other quotes and comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598573/how-influential-was-lorenz-work

Comment: It's not surprising at all.  Robert Frost wrote The Road Not Taken in 1920, a poem which contemplates the enormous magnitude of the consequences of a very marginal decision, although the name the butterfly effect only came later.

Comment: The history site has https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5453/poincare-quote-regarding-instability, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/edward-lorenz-and-sensitivity-to-initial-conditions

Comment: @RobertFrost I don't think what you said is true. Lorenz was a first class mathematician and he was surprised by it to a certain degree. To say that the phenomenon is "not surprising at all" is at best a not accurate statement.

Comment: @BigbearZzz but I don't think it was even new news, it has always been well known. Are you sure he was even surprised? It stands to reason that a chaotic or unstable system will behave... unpredicatbly.

Comment: Lorenz basically had no real part in the history of chaos, he was not even a mathematician. As you should know, Poincaré was there much before. Lorenz just presented a simple example among many others that have been found along the years.

Comment: @JohnB He was a mathematician before turning to a meteorologist during the war, so I assumed that he had a fair share of knowledge of the contemporary mathematics back then, but again, I could very well be wrong.

Comment: Could it be that around 1960 was the time that computers became widespread enough and fast enough that numerical experiments of any kind became possible (and not hidden away for national security reasons)? I.e., before it was too expensive or had a too long wait time to run the same computation multiple times "on a lark" so that the first and only result was almost always The Result?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Three modes taken from a Galerkin approximation is as far as we can get from any model of reality. It may, perhaps, but quite unlikely be any meaningful model. I like a lot the comment of LutzL, which might be the best way of seeing it. Incidentally, something similar happened with the Mandelbrot set, really Brooks-Matelski set (1978), but there was apparently no related mathematics before (which was not the case with Lorenz and the related work of Poincaré, even more in case Lorenz was in mathematics before that).

Comment: Other than this I would like to note something that is often forgotten: Mary Cartwright discovered essentially the same phenomenon as Lorenz but 20 years before, via the Van der Pol equation.

Comment: I've also heard of Poincare's infamous work on his analysis of 3 bodies problem. It could be the case that the person writing the book I read was just not very informed about the state of mathematics at the time so he only focused on Lorenz work.

Comment: Popular science books are written in a special way, they don't need to be that rigorous. By "infamous" do you mean the huge seminal work leading to a whole new mathematics and particularly to the modern theory of dynamical system, with rapid and overwhelming evolution at least for one century? Basically, it is where most of the modern theory began. Just for a starter: even the version with the mistake (before replacement) had already the recurrence theorem. Peculiar wording indeed... :)

Comment: @JohnB And even Van der Pol himself observed strange kind of oscillations when he was working with electronic devices, before Cartwright and Littlewood. I think that was either in P. Holmes reviews on history of dynamical systems or in Aubrey's _Writing the History of Dynamical Systems and Chaos: Longue Durée and Revolution, Disciplines and Cultures_ : someone described electrical scheme with a headphones that allowed perception of oscillations as a sound. P.S. Found similar quote [here](http://www.me.rochester.edu/courses/ME406/webexamp5/vanpol.pdf)